# Tracking upload progress of asset upload

Tags: usergrid

Can I track the upload progress of asset when attaching to an entity using the javascript SDK? Also my image is base64 encoded and embedded within a div (indeed as a img src attribute). When I try to attach this as a binary content I get the error as "readAsBinaryString is not an object". I used atob to do this conversion. Will this SDK request this in some specific format or do I just need to pass this binary content which I got as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not supported by the Usergrid API or Usergrid SDKs. You could probably work around it using HTML5, but more than likely you'd have to fake it.

Comment: Thanks remus for the reply.